# JPA entities: How to establish relationship between Parent and multiple Child classes

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I have the following Java classes:

```
public Class Parent {

    int someValue1;

    ChildType child;
}


public Class ChildType {

     int someValue2;
}


public Class ChildA extends ChildType {

     int id;

     String string;
}



public Class ChildB extends ChildType {

    int id;

    Integer integer;
}
```

I need to represent Parent, ChildA and ChildB as entity beans with each having a related table in the database.

When I load a Parent I also need to load either ChildA or ChildB depending on the relationship.

Comment: are you trying to map your beans to existent tables?

Comment: take a look on this http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Joined.2C_Multiple_Table_Inheritance

Comment: I'm open to change the tables if needed

Comment: thanks for the link, apparently using `@DiscriminatorColumn` is what I need.

Comment: There are various strategies available for the same.  Here is a nice link http://blog.xebia.com/2009/06/21/jpa-implementation-patterns-mapping-inheritance-hierarchies/

Comment: @ps0604 if this approach works, don't forget to post the answer and accept it here, so it will help others :-)

Comment: Cannot figure this out. I don't know how to map in class Parent the child tables. The id of each child table is independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i got that right, class parent is an entity that keeps a **one-to-one relationship** with ChildType entity. Also ChildType is an abstract entity with 2 implementations, ChildA and ChildB.

***So the JPA annotations configuration for each one of the entities, could be like that:***

```
 Parent class as Entity
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class Parent { // better name will do the job, because parent is often called
                      // the higher level class of the same hierarchy
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "SOME_VALUE") //if you need to persist it
  private int someValue1;

  @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "FK_PARENT_ID")
  private ChildType child;

  // getters and setters
}
```

```
 ChildType class as Entity
```

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class ChildType { // this one is actually called parent class

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
  @Column(name = "CHILDTYPE_ID")
  protected Long id;

  @Column(name = "SOME_VALUE_2")
  private int someValue2; // or maybe protected. Depends if you need childs to access it

  @Column(name = "A_STRING")
  private String string; // or maybe protected. Depends if you need childs to access it
  
  // getters and setters
}
```

### Finally we have ChildA and ChildB

***As you can see there is no need to have id fields on ChildType child classes, because
they inherit this field from ChildType!***

```
 ChildA as Entity
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD_A")
public Class ChildA extends ChildType {
  
  @Column(name = "A_STRING")
  private String string;
  
  // getters and setters
}
```

```
 ChildB as Entity
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD_B")
public Class ChildB extends ChildType {
  
  @Column(name = "AN_Integer")
  private Integer integer;
  
  // getters and setters
}
```

---

### More information about JPA Inheritance

check here:

- [Java Persistence/Inheritance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance)
- [Java EE tutorial Entity Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html)

Comment: does this mean that the ids of ChildA and ChildB are auto-generated and also independent as each child is a table with its id?

Comment: I usually declare`@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` in the id to be generated sequentially instead of `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)`

Comment: "does this mean ... with its id?"
-Yes as they just inherit the defined properties from their superclass.
"I usually declare ..."
- I do that in order to ensure the uniqueness of the id (as you wanted). I think that, with GenerationType.IDENTITY, you will get a more polymorphic like result in your code, because the id will increment every time you commit a new entity of type ChildType and not independently as ChildA or ChildB. 
you can check it here: [Auto Generated Values](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated)

Comment: Thanks, one last thing. Since `@JoinColumn(name = "FK_PARENT_ID")` points to either ChildA or ChildB, it seems that I need two columns instead of one, the first column will tell me the type of child, whereas the second column will tell me the id of that child. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: I'm getting `ChildType table not found` if I use `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` if I replace with `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` the error goes away

Comment: i originaly use that option as InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS, but you said that you needed both ChildType and it's implementations to have seperate tables, so i guessed that you wanted 3 tables for the hierarhy. I actually didn't see that you will run to a problem with the JOINED option, sorry for that! Anyways i recomend you (if it's not a prob to you) to keep TABLE_PER_CLASS. I will edit my answer in order to be acceptable from you.

Comment: Thanks.  Please see my previous comment on having two columns in the foreign key.

Comment: "Since @JoinColumn(name = "FK_PARENT_ID") [...] assumption correct?"
- With @JoinColumn annotation you actually create an unidirectional one-to-one association that goes from parent entity to ChildType and it's subclasses. So the point is the client classes of ChildType, like your Parent class, to be unable to distinguish if you pass ChildA or ChildB. Better, ChildType and it's subclasses should be related with the "is a" rule. If you break that, you break one of base principles of objective programming, that is polymorphism.

Comment: So even if the joined field is on superclass it effects it's subclasses to.
more info here: [Annotation JoinColumn](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/JoinColumn)

Comment: But what would happen if ChildA id = 1 and ChildB id = 1? How will the parent class store the values of the relationship?

Comment: please check here: [Inheritance and custom types (Hibernate)](http://what-when-how.com/hibernate/inheritance-and-custom-types-hibernate/)
Pay more attention, at the Table per class sections, i think that this will answer big part of your questions and give you a way to start working on this domain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67575/discussion-between-gregoavg-and-ps0604).